# discord.pyを並列処理のスレッド内で動かしたい

Tags: python, python3, discord

このようなBotを作っています。

- 毎日挨拶を行うBot
- guildごとに何時何分にあいさつするかを設定できる

on_readyでwhile Trueループを使ってみようと思っているのですが、問題はボットの通知対象guildが多くて、単純なループでは処理できない点です。
並列実行しないといけません。

このようなBotを作ったことがある人、そうでない人も、何か解決策を教えてください。

Answer (score 1):

`client.loop.create_task(関数)`というものを発見しました。
ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

- 挨拶する時間、挨拶する相手、挨拶の内容（＋補足情報）のクラスを作る
- 上記クラスに`self`の情報を元に投稿する`挨拶`メソッドを定義する
- インスタンスが作成されたら、挨拶する時間をキーに`Dictionary`に登録する
- `n`分毎に繰り替えすメインループ又は`Timer`ループ内で、`Dictionary`から現在時刻がキーのインスタンスを取得する
- 現在時刻キーのインスタンスが`Dictionary`になければなにもしない
- インスタンスが存在すれば、`挨拶`メソッドを実行する

上記手法でスレッド１本でbot化出来る様な気がします。お試し下さい。

Comment: ごめんなさい、使用を伝えてなかったですね。guildごとに通知時刻が違うので無限ループを複数回さないといけないのです...